# How to write Junit for Talend joblet?

Tags: java, junit, talend

We are trying to write junit for Talend joblet, but the create test option is not available.

What is the alternative way to do this?

Basically, we are trying to automate the test case when we build the talend projects through jenkins.

Any good link for this will help a lot.

Comment: The test case option is only available in the commercial subscription version. I am not aware of a way to do this in the free version.

Comment: @tobi6 : we are using licensed one only, but it seems we can't write a test case for joblet.

Comment: If you are using the commercial version, please talk to Talend Support for help. They help quickly and are very competent.